# Locus of Points equidistant from two points

Tags: geometry

I'm reviewing geometry using Coxeter's book. Somewhere in the book talks about Locus of Points equidistant from two points which I do not quite understand. And is there any book about Cartesian coordinate like part II of H.S.M. Coxeter's Introduction to geometry but with more explanation and not a general calculus text. Thank.[image]

[image]

Comment: Perpendicular bisector.

Comment: How the author got the first formula?

Comment: Can you verify that the equation represents points $(x,y)$ equidistant from the two given points?

Comment: @Cathy Expand the first equation and see if you get $l=0$.

Comment: @OliverJones I'm confused about whether L=0 means ax+by+c = 0? And is any intuition behind this equation or it's just pure algebraic manipulation? why it says p1 to L=0 is something and P1 to the line is another thing in the last two lines? Isn't L = 0 is the line?

Comment: @Cathy Yes, that's what it means. It represents points $(x,y)$ in the plane that lie on this line. Have you seen the equation $y=mx+b$? It's the same thing.

Comment: @Cathy I think $P_1$ represents $(x_1-2al_1,y_1-2bl_1)$. I can't tell because you haven't posted the whole text. $P_2$ will be the other point $(x_1,y_1)$. The line $l=0$ passes between these two points. If you join $P_1$ and $P_2$ by a line segment, it will be perpendicular to $l=0$ and the intersection is the foot.